# Exponent of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

In the context of algebra of limits, the algebraic operations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication and devisions are well explored in text book however the exponent is less explored. More precisely,

Let Let $\{x_n\}$ and  $\{y_n\}$ be two real sequences such that, $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}.$ For what values of $x$ and $y$ do we get ${x_n}^{y_n} \rightarrow x^y?$ and how to prove it?

I understand, if $x=1, y=\infty$  then we can connot conclude anything about $x_n^{y_n}$ in general. What about other values?

Any particular reason to avoid  exponent of two sequences in textbooks?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It works in frames of continuous functions: $x_n^{y_n}=e^{y_n \ln x_n}$. From here you find major cases.